# Error Handling in PowerShell - inspect error output from external programs

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I have a script that runs a batch file. The batch file is throwing some errors, but runs successfully. But when the batch file throws errors, the powershell script throws an error.

Included in the output is "0 failed". Is there a way to check to check to see if the code contains this message, and if it does then to ignore all errors?

Here is some psuedocode that might be able to describe what I am trying to accomplish.

```
$output = ./testrunner.bat 
if ($output -Like "(0 failed)") { 
    # ignore errors
} else {
    # don't ignore errors 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not easy to **selectively capture stderr output from an external utility (console application) in a variable**.

The most concise, though somewhat obscure approach is (PSv4+):

```bash
# First, make sure that $ErrorActionPreference is at its default,
# 'Continue'

$stdout, $stderr = (./testrunner.bat 2>&1).Where({
  $_ -is [string]
}, 'Split')
```

Note: If you're content to collect the *combined* stdout/stderr output in a *single* variable, the task simplifies to:

```bash
$output = ./testrunner.bat 2>&1
```

Note that the variables in both scenarios will contain **an *array* of objects representing the collection of the individual output *lines***: stdout lines become (as onw would expect) `[string]` array elements, whereas PS converts stderr lines to `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` instances.

You can then **inspect the `$stderr` (or `$output`) variable for the success/failure indicator substring** - note the use of enclosing wildcard characters `*`, because `-like` always matches against the *entire* string (unlike the regex-matching `-match` operator):

```bash
if ($stderr -like '*(0 failed)*') {
    # ignore errors
} else {
    # don't ignore errors 
}
```

---

As for **what you experienced**:

> when the batch file throws errors, the powershell script throws an error.

External programs, including batch files *cannot* throw errors in a PowerShell sense; they integrate as follows:

- Their exit code is recorded in `$LASTEXITCODE`, and `$?` is set to `$True` if
  `$LASTEXITCODE` is `0`, and `$False` otherwise.
- In the *regular console*, stderr output is passed through to the console - *not* colored in red - and *not* logged in `$Error` (the in-memory log of errors). In other words: stdout and stderr lines are *formatted* the same.
- Unfortunately, the *ISE* behaves differently and *does* print stderr lines as if they were PowerShell errors and *does* log them in `$Error` - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3996#issuecomment-308198184).

Therefore, it sounds like you were running from the *ISE*.
Additionally, if `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` is in effect when you run your code from the ISE, not only would the first stderr line present as a PowerShell error, but it would trigger termination of your entire PowerShell script.